# late static binding in closure PHP5.5 vs 5.6

Tags: php, php-5.5, php-5.6

Why `new static` in the closure (in a class `static` method) is equal to `new self` in PHP5.5, while it's properly bound in PHP5.6 ?

Given:

```
abstract class Parent {
    public function __construct($something)
    {
        $this->something = $something;
    }

    public static function make($array)
    {
        return array_map(function ($el) {
            return new static($el);
        }, $array);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

}
```

then

```
Child::make($someArray); 
// PHP5.5 FatalError: cannot instantiate abstract class Parent
// PHP5.6 works fine, as expected
```

In 5.5 this will work as expected:

```
public static function make($array)
{
    $child = get_called_class();

    return array_map(function ($el) use ($chlid) {
        return new $child($el);
    }, $array);
}
```

but why is this happening? I haven't found any mentions on php.net concerning static binding changes in 5.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66622), fixed in [5.5.14](http://3v4l.org/lk4i0#v5514).

Comment: Yep. Even more interesting is that it had been fixed already in [5.4.30](http://3v4l.org/lk4i0#v5430) through 5.4.38, but apparently not included in 5.5.0. Thanks

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk: php supports multiple branches at a time, so any 5.4.* not necessarily precedes 5.5.*. In this case, 5.4.30 and 5.5.14 was released on the [same day](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php).

Comment: Sure. I wasn't aware of the release dates :)